# Uncaught TypeError: tplContent.importNode is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, html5-template, html-imports

i'm reading the book "Web Components mit Polymer" and tried the following Code from the Book:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<template id="tpl">
    <h1 class="title"></h1>
    <div class="body"></div>
</template>
<script>
    var tplContent = document.getElementById("tpl").content;
    var node = tplContent.importNode(true);
    node.querySelector("h1").textContent = "Hallo Welt";
    node.querySelector("div").textContent = "Ich komme aus einem Template";
    document.body.appendChild(node);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But i just get stopped in the second JS line with the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: tplContent.importNode is not a function

I use Google Chrome version 63.0.3239.84 on Ubuntu. 
Can someone help me with this oder?

Regards,
Artur

Answer (score 1):

`importNode` should be called on `document`, not an element in the document.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<template id="tpl">
    <h1 class="title"></h1>
    <div class="body"></div>
</template>
<script>
    var tplContent = document.getElementById("tpl").content;

    // importNode is a method of document:
    var node = document.importNode(tplContent, true);

    node.querySelector("h1").textContent = "Hallo Welt";
    node.querySelector("div").textContent = "Ich komme aus einem Template";
    document.body.appendChild(node);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode)**:

> The **Document** method `importNode()` creates a new copy of the specified
>   Node or DocumentFragment from another document so that it can be
>   inserted into the current Document. It is not yet included in the
>   document tree; to do that, you need to call a method such as
>   `appendChild()` or `insertBefore()`.

Additional information on using `<template>` and `document.importNode()` **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)**.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error here:

```
var node = tplContent.importNode(true);
```

`tpl` does not have the function `importNode()`

If you want to use [importNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode):

```
var node = document.importNode(tplContent, true);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<template id="tpl">
    <h1 class="title"></h1>
    <div class="body"></div>
</template>
<script>
    var tplContent = document.getElementById("tpl").content;
    var node = document.importNode(tplContent, true);
    node.querySelector("h1").textContent = "Hallo Welt";
    node.querySelector("div").textContent = "Ich komme aus einem Template";
    document.body.appendChild(node);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatly you can use the [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) method on `<template>`'s `content`.

```
var tplContent = document.getElementById("tpl").content;
var node = tplContent.cloneNode(true);
```